# PowerShell steps to fix slow startup

Tags: powershell, console, startup

I have slow PowerShell console startup times (always more than 5 second wait) and was hoping for advice on troubleshooting steps to find out where the bottlenecks might be?

I have read that for running scripts, `-NoProfile` is important to prevent Modules etc loading, but how, in general, should we approach finding out what is slowing things down? I don't have many Modules installed and I know that since PowerShell 3.0, Modules are just *referenced* at startup and not fully loaded (a Module is only fully loaded when a function from a given Module is invoked) so I just can't understand why it takes 5+ seconds to start a bare console (my $profile also is empty).

Any advice on various steps that I can look at to debug the console startup process would be appreciated? Also, are there maybe some Microsoft or third-party tools that exist to debug the various steps in the console startup process to look for bottlenecks?

Comment: See [Powershell slow starting on Windows 10](https://superuser.com/a/1411591/1132585)

Comment: Update: updating to windows 11 fixed startup time from 4+ seconds to ~0.5 seconds

Comment: That's interesting, most of my machines fail the upgrade compatibility check, think it's all about TPM or something. But a lot of hardware has been made redundant by Microsoft's Win 11 bullying unfortunately :(

Answer (score 35):

When PowerShell starts to become slow at startup, an update of the .NET framework might be the cause.
To speed up again, use `ngen.exe` on PowerShell's assemblies.
It generate native images for an assembly and its dependencies and install them in the Native Images Cache.

Run this as **Administrator**

```
$env:PATH = [Runtime.InteropServices.RuntimeEnvironment]::GetRuntimeDirectory()
[AppDomain]::CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies() | ForEach-Object {
    $path = $_.Location
    if ($path) { 
        $name = Split-Path $path -Leaf
        Write-Host -ForegroundColor Yellow "`r`nRunning ngen.exe on '$name'"
        ngen.exe install $path /nologo
    }
}
```

Hope that helps

Comment: Thanks for that Theo, but that did not affect my startup times at all (I also did a full reboot afterwards in case that might help, but no luck). This is useful as part of steps to take though, maybe it helps other folks. Any other ideas for seeing why console startup is slow?

Comment: @YorSubs  I found some other things you can try [here](https://superuser.com/questions/1212442/powershell-slow-starting-on-windows-10)

Comment: Thanks Theo, that is a very interesting article and I've gone through them all but no luck. I might have regained 0.5 seconds on startup from following all of these, but it's still remarkably slow (by remarkable, I find it really bad that opening a console on a modern OS with a very fast modern i5 CPU is taking 5+ second open - I mean, if a console is not opening in less than 1 second, that's not a good advertisement for PowerShell to say the least!).

Comment: Somehow, the initial startup of my Windows 10 built-in powershell (5.1.x) is noticeably faster compared to powershell 7.1.2 (downloaded from official GitHub repository). It's a real shame something has to rely on many different external libraries/frameworks to even show up.

Comment: @Theo It worked for my case, after running the script it loads in 1 sec.

Comment: i have no idea what that code is doing, and yer saying to run it as admin??

Comment: @JarettLloyd It runs [ngen.exe](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/tools/ngen-exe-native-image-generator) to compile the assemblies used by PowerShell. Once compiled, they load MUCH faster that when not compiled (just-in-time) and yes, you need to run this as administrator.

Comment: This code just calls the ahead of time to pre-compile the code. Exactly what I was looking for. Thanks.

Comment: ngen is part of dotnet framework.

Comment: Awesome, oldi but goldie. I have a .net App, that calls various powershell-scripts, 5-20 every second. CPU during spawning the processes was on average 75% on 16 cores. After optimizing, Startup of powershell is noticeable faster, now keeping the cores chilled at about 8-10% average load.

Answer (score 7):

in my case, it was Anaconda that caused the loading of my profile to take long time. After I removed this region:

```bash
#region conda initialize
# !! Contents within this block are managed by 'conda init' !!
(& "C:\Users\USERNAME\anaconda3\Scripts\conda.exe" "shell.powershell" "hook") | Out-String | Invoke-Expression
#endregion
```

from my **C:\Users\USERNAME\OneDrive\Documents\WindowsPowerShell[profile.ps1|Microsoft.PowerShell_profile.ps1]** paths, the loading became instant.

But, of course, you must know it won't cause any problems in your case.

Answer (score 6):

My work computer stored the main profile on a remote server. Another minor problem was that it imported duplicate modules from 4 different profile.ps1 files.

Use the following commands to see where your profiles and modules are stored. Delete the unnecessary profile.ps1 and move all your modules into one directory.

```
echo $env:PSModulePath

$profile | select *
```

My loading time was reduced from 21000ms to 1300ms.

Comment: It never really occured to me that the reason for the slowness was onedrive. I thought I had disabled Syncing the documents folder ages ago, and your answer pointed me in the right direction.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, `pwsh` tends to be slow.

**Check your profiles.**
It's better for startup time only one to exist. Some apps (like `conda`) like to add something to a shared profile. Clean if something is not yours.

```
$profile | Select-Object -Property *
```

**Use [Runspaces](https://adamtheautomator.com/powershell-multithreading/) to make your module imports lazily loaded.** We can import a module in a different (background) thread and then use that already loaded module in our session. Look at the code below:

```
$LazyLoadProfileRunspace = [RunspaceFactory]::CreateRunspace()
$LazyLoadProfile = [PowerShell]::Create()
$LazyLoadProfile.Runspace = $LazyLoadProfileRunspace
$LazyLoadProfileRunspace.Open()
[void]$LazyLoadProfile.AddScript({Import-Module posh-git}) # (1)
[void]$LazyLoadProfile.BeginInvoke()
$null = Register-ObjectEvent -InputObject $LazyLoadProfile -EventName InvocationStateChanged -Action {
    Import-Module -Name posh-git # (2)
    $global:GitPromptSettings.DefaultPromptPrefix.Text = 'PS '
    $global:GitPromptSettings.DefaultPromptBeforeSuffix.Text = '`n'
    $LazyLoadProfile.Dispose()
    $LazyLoadProfileRunspace.Close()
    $LazyLoadProfileRunspace.Dispose()
}
```

As you can notice we have to describe modules we want to lazy load twice. First time for a background thread that will be actually loading it and the second for our actual thread. Ofc don't forget to clean things up at the end (close & dispose used).

This method is applicable only for modules or global variables - all your background thread-local variables/functions/etc won't come to your console session.

*Note: It is a workaround. It's not truly lazy - we just put things with heavy time impact in the background and when it's ready we start using it (It's more of delayed initialization). That's why if you have something you need to use immediately after the shells console pop-up then you shouldn't use this technique.*

**Optional 1:** For further investigation you can use [PSProfiler](https://github.com/IISResetMe/PSProfiler).

```
Install-Module PSProfiler
Import-Module PSProfiler
Measure-Script -Top 3 $profile
```

**Optional 2.** Generate native images. This one didn't help me, but helped others. You need to have Visual Studio installed and run the code below in `Developer Powershell for VS 20xx` with Admin permissions:

```
$env:PATH = [Runtime.InteropServices.RuntimeEnvironment]::GetRuntimeDirectory()
[AppDomain]::CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies() | ForEach-Object {
    $path = $_.Location
    if ($path) { 
        $name = Split-Path $path -Leaf
        Write-Host -ForegroundColor Yellow "`r`nRunning ngen.exe on '$name'"
        ngen.exe install $path /nologo
    }
}
```

**Optional 3.** Add `powershell.exe` and `pwsh.exe` or both to Windows Defender exclusions. Didn't help me but helped others.

Answer (score 2):

Found this solution when I googled having the same problem, but in 2022. Unfortunately this did not fix my issue.

Our systems have a group policy security requirement to "Turn on PowerShell Transcription". The policy requires that we specify "the Transcript output directory to point to a Central Log Server or another secure location". The server name changed and no one updated the policy. As soon as I updated the GPO with the new location, PowerShell opened instantly again.

Answer (score 1):

If your machine does not have direct access to the internet, the following solution may help.

*This solution is lifted from comments on [this  PowerShell Issue](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/10983#issuecomment-779819256) summarised by eizedev.*

I'd recommend just following this comment but for the sake of SO guidelines, I've reproduced some of it here:

## Cause

For machines disconnected from the internet, there is still an attempt retrieve a Certificate Revocation list from the internet, and this request must time-out before the PowerShell start-up process completes.

*In particular this is during the import of module PSReadLine*

## Solution

Consider methods to make these lists available to machines without direct internet access.
(eg a configure a Certificate Revocation List Distribution Point?)

## Workaround

The workaround, is to reduce time-outs from 15 seconds to 1 second for any system certificate checks on the disconnected machines.

### *WARNING this change is system wide - it doesn't just affect PowerShell.*

Please see the linked PowerShell issue thread for complete considerations before executing this.

```
# Create the keys if missing 
If((Test-Path 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\SystemCertificates\ChainEngine') -eq $false ) { New-Item -Path 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\SystemCertificates\ChainEngine' -Force -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue }
If((Test-Path 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\SystemCertificates\ChainEngine\Config') -eq $false ) { New-Item -Path 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\SystemCertificates\ChainEngine\Config' -Force -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue }

# Set Timeout values to 1 second (1000 ms)
New-ItemProperty -Path "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\SystemCertificates\ChainEngine\Config" -Name ChainUrlRetrievalTimeoutMilliseconds -Value 1000 -PropertyType DWORD -Force
New-ItemProperty -Path "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\SystemCertificates\ChainEngine\Config" -Name ChainRevAccumulativeUrlRetrievalTimeoutMilliseconds -Value 1000 -PropertyType DWORD -Force
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, it was taking ~2 seconds to load and no time at all with **-NoProfile** option.

What worked for me is to remove from the profile (editing it with **vim $PROFILE**) file all lines that started with **Import-Module**, which I guess were not necessary because all the modules work anyway.

I'm pretty new to Powershell, so I'm not sure what that means, but now it loads fast, it doesn't even show the time it takes.

Answer (score -3):

Press Windows+R
Type %temp% and hit enter
C+A & SHIFT+DEL
That should do it

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: It is mandatory to empty the trash bin first though!

Comment: Your answer implies that temporary files are cause for the slowness to start... which is one of the myriads of potential causes.

Comment: This doesn't fix anything. Not sure why deleting temp files has anything to do with slow startup of PowerShell.