# Powershell takes minutes to load script / show prompt

Tags: powershell, wait, prompt

on Windows 10 21H1 with Powershell 5.1.19041.1 it takes minutes to load PS to even get a prompt:

- If I start powershell from CMD --> minutes to prompt
- If I start Windows Powershell ISE --> minutes to prompt
- If I run a PS script --> minutes to execute the actual code

I have just found out what only works directly is:

- If I start "powershell -Version 2.0" from CMD --> seconds to prompt

There is nothing mentioned in the event logs. I already uninstalled and reinstalled Powershell from "optionalfeatures.exe" without any effort.

Does anyone has a clue or an idea to which dialog/logfile/whatever to look at?

Best regards,
Api

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PowerShell steps to fix slow startup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59341482/powershell-steps-to-fix-slow-startup)

Comment: What happens if you run with the -NoProfile switch? `powershell.exe -NoProfile`

Comment: Hi Daniel, -NoProfile unfortunately does not work. Takes also minutes to prompt.

Comment: Can anyone give me a hint how to reset the Powershell profile and how to completely uninstall / install PowerShell? In Optionalfeatures.exe I can only choose Powershell 2.0 to be installed/uninstalled. However the new versions seem to have some different way of setup?!

Comment: @Scepticalist: No that doesn't.